# Network port reuse

Tags: sockets, networking, connection, switching

Imagine there's relatively complex network infrastructure, from PC, then intelligent hub, then router, then area network switches, then internet, and then same chain of devices towards the server.

Imagine I make HTTP request from some local PC's IP address and some its local port, to the remote server's port 80 (HTTP). Under normal circumstances communication goes from connection request packet, through acknowledgments and requests, and then finally till the finalization and channel close. All intelligent network devices can see this communication, and act accordingly.

Now imagine the following situation: PC makes request from its IP address and some fixed source port, receives half of data, and then reboots. After reboot it again makes request from same IP address and same source port.

Question - which possible behavior it will cause at network devices involved? How are they going to handle previous session before PC reboots?

This is very open ended question, and I need your view onto the situation. It is caused by me having strange problems with embedded network device, which reuses port numbers after power-cycle. I plan to see what is going on on the network using Wireshark, but need direction where to look at. Thank you.

Edit: I am adding proxy server(s) into the chain (which can work higher level than layer-3).

Comment: The interesting thing about routers is that they switch each packet, at layer-3, independently of any other packets which may have come before. Routers don't care what happens at layer-4 (ports are layer-4 addresses).

Comment: The reused source IP:port pair will either encounter a TIME_WAIT state at the server on the prior connection, which will cause a connection reset/refusal, or it won't, so a new connection will be formed, with a new initial sequence number etc.